# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: json, flutter

How to solve these problems Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
on your programme [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaAl1.png)

First, I made a login page and entered my email and password, and every time I entered the email and password correctly, this error appears. I entered the email and password correctly, but this error appeared to me, and everything I entered incorrectly showed me this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18ZS4.png)

```
 login() async {
    EasyLoading.show(status: 'loading...');

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("${Const_Values.BASEURL}login.php"),
      body: {"email_address": emailControllor.text, "pas": passwordControllor.text},

    );
    EasyLoading.dismiss();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (jsonBody['result']) {
        General.savePrefString(Const_Values.ID, jsonBody['id ']);
        General.savePrefString(Const_Values.USER_NAME, jsonBody['user_name']);
        General.savePrefString(Const_Values.EMAIL_ADDRESS, jsonBody['email_address']);
        General.savePrefString(Const_Values.PASSWORD, jsonBody['pas']);
        General.savePrefString(Const_Values.ID_USER_TYPE, jsonBody['id_user_type ']);
        if(jsonBody['id_user_type ']=="2"){
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return Main_Enduser_Serceen();
              },
            ),
          );
        }else{
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return Main_Admin_Secreen();
              },
            ),
          );
        }

      } else {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              icon: Icon(Icons.error),
              content: Text(jsonBody['msg']),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Text("OK"),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please show your code. Not pictures. Code. It's text. Copy it and paste it into your question and format it.

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem please try to debug the `jsonBody` and check whether what is value you are getting inside `jsonBody["result"]`.
According to the log statement the if condition needs a bool value but you are getting a null value for `jsonBody["result"]` so either add a `print(jsonBody["result"]);` before the if condition i.e. line 231 and check what value you are getting in it.

For your second problem could be please print the `jsonBody` and share here because you might be getting some value as `int` in json and you are storing in `String` format without converting it to `String` so try this below code and check whether it is working or else send the `jsonBody` to debug it further.

```
General.savePrefString(Const_Values.ID, jsonBody['id '].toString());
General.savePrefString(Const_Values.USER_NAME, jsonBody['user_name'].toString());
General.savePrefString(Const_Values.EMAIL_ADDRESS, jsonBody['email_address'].toString());
General.savePrefString(Const_Values.PASSWORD, jsonBody['pas'].toString());
General.savePrefString(Const_Values.ID_USER_TYPE, jsonBody['id_user_type '].toString());
```